# Huggin Face Conversational error: error: argument --model: invalid choice: 'models/' (choose from 'openai-gpt', 'gpt2')

Tags: python, nlp, gpt-2

I´m trying to replicate the results of this repo:

https://github.com/huggingface/transfer-learning-conv-ai

For that I'm following the basic example that is not based on docker:

```
git clone https://github.com/huggingface/transfer-learning-conv-ai
cd transfer-learning-conv-ai
pip install -r requirements.txt
python -m spacy download en
```

Then I try:

```
python3 interact.py --model models/
```

And there I get this error:

```
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
usage: interact.py [-h] [--dataset_path DATASET_PATH]
                   [--dataset_cache DATASET_CACHE] [--model {openai-gpt,gpt2}]
                   [--model_checkpoint MODEL_CHECKPOINT]
                   [--max_history MAX_HISTORY] [--device DEVICE] [--no_sample]
                   [--max_length MAX_LENGTH] [--min_length MIN_LENGTH]
                   [--seed SEED] [--temperature TEMPERATURE] [--top_k TOP_K]
                   [--top_p TOP_P]
interact.py: error: argument --model: invalid choice: 'models/' (choose from 'openai-gpt', 'gpt2')
```

First thing I notice is that there was not any "models" directory hence I created one and tried again, got the same error.

Second thing I tried was to download the model as in the repo it specifies:

```
We make a pretrained and fine-tuned model available on our S3 here
```

From that link I tried:

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/transfer-learning-chatbot/finetuned_chatbot_gpt.tar.gz
```

And uncompress the files both in the main directory and  in the models directory and tried again.

For the third time, I  tried and got the same error.

This is the current structure of my working dir:

```
Dockerfile   config.json                   interact.py              pytorch_model.bin       train.py
LICENCE      convai_evaluation.py          merges.txt               requirements.txt        utils.py
README.md    example_entry.py              model_training_args.bin  special_tokens.txt      vocab.json
__pycache__  finetuned_chatbot_gpt.tar.gz  models                   test_special_tokens.py
```

**EDIT**

Tried kimbo´s sugestion:

```
python3 interact.py --model gpt2
```

I get this error now:

```
 File "interact.py", line 154, in <module>
    run()
  File "interact.py", line 114, in run
    raise ValueError("Interacting with GPT2 requires passing a finetuned model_checkpoint")
ValueError: Interacting with GPT2 requires passing a finetuned model_checkpoint
```

Also tried just runing:

```
python3 interact.py
```

For that I have not get any error, it seems to get stuck at this point:

```
INFO:/home/lramirez/transfer-learning-conv-ai/utils.py:Download dataset from https://s3.amazonaws.com/datasets.huggingface.co/personachat/personachat_self_original.json
INFO:/home/lramirez/transfer-learning-conv-ai/utils.py:Tokenize and encode the dataset
```

I have been there for about 30min

Comment: Are you still stuck on this or did my answer work?

Comment: @kimbo have not tested it yet, Will accept it once I do it

Answer (score 1):

#### New Update

It's taking forever to tokenize the dataset because it's tokenizing the entire dataset, which is a 200 MB JSON file.

To make it MUCH faster, just load part of the dataset.

Open up utils.py and change the `tokenize` function:

```py
def tokenize(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        return tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenizer.tokenize(obj))
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return dict((n, tokenize(o)) for n, o in obj.items())
    limit = 100  # <- this is the number of items in the dataset to load
    return list(tokenize(o) for o in obj[:limit])  # <- change it here
```

That will only load the first 100 items in the dataset.

---

#### Old Answer

When I'm unsure how to use a python script (or anything you run from the command line, really), I usually try a couple things to figure it out.

- `python script.py -h` or `python script.py --help`. Often that will print out an explanation of the arguments the script is expecting and how to run it.
- If it's an executable command you installed, I always try `man <executable>`. Probably won't work in this case since you just cloned the repo from GitHub and didn't install anything.
- If I still don't understand how to use the script because the above didn't work, I go online and look for some documentation (a Github README, a wiki, readthedocs, etc)
- If it's documented poorly, I just look at the source code. Sometimes I skip straight to this part because for smaller stuff it's often quicker.

In this case, I read the README on Github and that didn't tell me all that much, so I took a look at interact.py. If you look starting at line 139 (https://github.com/huggingface/transfer-learning-conv-ai/blob/master/interact.py#L139), it appears they're in a while loop, waiting for you to input something to feed to the model.

/end update

This part:

```
(choose from 'openai-gpt', 'gpt2')
```

should tell you all you need to know.

Try running

```
python3 interact.py --model gpt2
```

or

```
python3 interact.py --model openai-gpt
```

Comment: I tried your sugestion, got a new error with that one. I updated the question with the details.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez Did this help?

Comment: I think the model is waiting for you to input something (try typing something into the terminal and then pressing Enter)

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez Never mind, tignore my last comment. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because HuggingFace don't have a fine-tuned model of GPT2 on ConvAI dataset, they only did it for GPT

```
if args.model == 'gpt2':
            raise ValueError("Interacting with GPT2 requires passing a finetuned model_checkpoint")
```

You can find this part of the code in the interact.py file, so if you want to have it on gpt2, you need to fine-tune it yourself. I was just struggling with this righ now.